# uploading image file in codeigniter with undefine alert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am having a problem in uploading my file and save it in the folder that I've destined. I have a tutorial from the other site and the code that was I've edited doesn't work. I am with CodeIgniter framework. I have an error also in my console with the error of

> "Uncaught TypeError: $.ajaxFileUpload is not a function" .

Here is my html:

```
<input type="file" name="userfile" class="file" id="userfile">
<div class="input-group col-xs-4">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i></span>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="browse btn btn-primary input-sm" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Browse</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

and also here is my script. I have a two script for my openfiledialog and upload submit button:

```
<script>
  $(document).on('click', '.browse', function() {
    var file = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.file');
    file.trigger('click');
  });
  $(document).on('change', '.file', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.form-control').val($(this).val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, ''));
  });
</script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#upload_file').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajaxFileUpload({
        url: '<?php echo site_url('
        manager / profile / upload_file ')?>',
        secureuri: false,
        fileElementId: 'userfile',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, status) {
          alert(data.msg);
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

and here is my controller to save the image file on my folder:

```
public function upload_file() {
  $status = "";
  $file_element_name = 'userfile';

  if ($status != "error") {
    $config['upload_path'] = APPPATH . 'images/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|doc|txt';
    $config['max_size'] = 1024 * 8;
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload($file_element_name)) {
      $status = 'error';
    } else {
      $data = $this->upload->data();

    }
    @unlink($_FILES[$file_element_name]);
  }
  echo json_encode(array('status' => $status));
}
```

Comment: Maybe the reason you're having that kind of error is you forgot to import the script (jquery plugin) before using it ?

Comment: i have already a plugin sir. do you mean the script src = jquery. i already have it. my openfiledialog works well

Comment: `$.ajaxFileUpload` is not part of jQuery core library... it is a third party plugin name and would require another script to be included in order to use it

Comment: ahwp.. can you state the plugin for upload sir ?

Comment: never seen it myself but you should see it mentioned in tutorial or can google that name. There are thousands of plugins around

Comment: the tutorial doesn't mentioned about the plugin sir.. so sorry. thanks for your answer.. is it only a script src= ?

Comment: @charlietfl sir ? .. is it a script src= ? the plugin you mean ?

Comment: yes and it most likely has a similar names as `ajaxFileUpload`

Comment: why still error sir.. i already have this include with my src. 
https://github.com/davgothic/AjaxFileUpload/blob/master/jquery.ajaxfileupload.js

Comment: @charlietfl why is it still error sir. I already have this include with my src

Comment: download that file from there... the link is incorrect to use in a live page

Comment: i already did sir but still error :'( 
same error
<script src="<?= base_url() ?>assets/manager/js/ajaxFileUpload.js"></script>

Comment: @charlietfl sir . no errors now but it shows undefined in alert

Comment: now you need to use proper path on server...base_url is not a file path

Comment: @charlietfl is that only the problem sir ? no other? can you check my code pls

Comment: @charlietfl sir i already created a good apppath. like this. . i created a folder insidde my application folder named: images
here is my upload path
 $config['upload_path'] = APPPATH . 'images/';
still undefined